# How can I know if an SQS message has been redriven from a DLQ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm working with SQS and configured a DLQ. I'm trying to understand if there's a standard way to identity that a message has been redriven from a DLQ to the origin queue or some best practice on how to achieve this? (some kind of built in attribute or any other mechanism).
I haven't seen an attribute for this in the documentations:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html

and when I redrive messages from a dlq to the origin queue there's no way I can see to add a custom attribute to the messages so that I can identify the redriven messages.

Comment: When you say "redriven", are you referring to [Configuring a dead-letter queue redrive (console) - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-dead-letter-queue-redrive.html)? There does not seem to be a way to identify which messages have been redriven in this way. You could write your own redrive script instead, which reads from the Dead Letter Queue and sends a message to the original queue with an additional message attribute or some information in the message itself.